# Concatenar strings em Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Tenho a seguinte função, que altera o valor numérico de uma string quando encontrado:

```
var original = "Este aqui é o valor do cliente 000.000.00 01";
var original = str.match(/\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\.\d\d \d\d/)
var novo = "129.000.000 02";
original = original.replace(/\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\.\d\d \d\d/g, novo);
```

O que eu preciso fazer é que quando ele encontrar e alterar o valor numérico os 2 números finais ele mantenha o da string original. No caso ai de cima, seria assim:

Resultado = `129.000.000 02`

O que eu preciso:

Resultado = `129.000.000 01` (esse `01` seria os 2 últimos dígitos da string original)

Comment: Juro que eu tentei, mas nao consigo entender o que tu precisa, tenta contextualizar mais

Comment: rsrssrs @FelipeKM essa foi boa. Vamos lá, vou ser prático.

Comment: @FelipeKM, editei a pergunta, veja se entendeu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize essa expressão `/\d{2}$/` para capturar os dois últimos números de uma *string*.

```
var foo = "Este aqui é o valor do cliente 000.000.00 01";
var number = foo.match(/\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\.\d\d \d\d/); // 000.000.00 01
var to_replace = "129.000.000 02";
var lastnumber = foo.match(/\d{2}$/); // 01
to_replace = to_replace.replace(/\d{2}$/, lastnumber);

alert("Valor original: " + number); // 000.000.00 01
alert("Novo valor: " + to_replace); // 129.000.000 01
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qdzdK/)