# É correto usar H1, H2 com display none a fim de SEO ou são penalizados pelos motores de busca?

Tags: seo, css-display

*Procurei aqui ,mas não achei nenhum tópico abordando. Se já houver, por favor, marquem como duplicata.*

Estou com um problema. O logotipo do meu cliente não pode ser reproduzido através de fontes e CSS limpo, e no nome dele contém palavras-chaves significantes, gostaria de aproveitá-las em títulos de nível a fim de *rankia-lo* melhor nos motores de busca.

Então usei **display:none** no **h1**, mas um colega me disse que pode ser que eu seja penalizado por isso. Isso é verdade?

Há alguma outra forma para melhorar isso? 
Por ex.: usando **position:absolute e left: -50000px**

Comment: Acho que isso aí pode ser considerado uma técnica de blackhat light.
Mas eu não entendi, se o nome dele não pode ser escrito como é que você os escreveu?

Comment: Quando uma pergunta é marcada como duplicata é automaticamente informado a você. Veja [como fica uma duplicata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16916/concatenar-strings-em-javascript).

Answer (score 4):

Não, não é correto, desde que não seja feito de forma abusiva. 
 
E sim, existe a penalização, por isso se pegarmos sites como: Vagas, Infojobs e Catho, a grande parte da densidade de palavras estão em: links, classes css, alts, titles, no próprio conteúdo da página e até em comentários, mas não de forma abusiva.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: valew enzo! salvou, hehe